# Tried everything scooter GY6 50-80cc will not start

Tags: starting, scooter, cranks-wont-run

Compression is very good, petcock works fine, CDI seams to work (tested with other one as well), have spark, just replace new stator and Narako coil, replaced vacuum hoses, side stand is up, have gas in the tank, cleaned carburetor. ​When checking sparkplug - it's dry, not getting gas. No idea why not, I check all the above.
Why is gas not getting in to cylinder? Crazy situation!

Scooter is Jinlung 50cc (2002) changed to 80cc was running perfect, and started in one click, then slowly over the time it took longer and longer to start at the end will not start.

I run out of ideas, I am exhausted and feel like a loser that I did not find the issue.

Possible options:
buy new carb, check valve clearance, check timing

Also the scooter is completely striped of plastic and back lights is not connected etc. (just in case that could have something to do)

Any good answer and solution is welcome.

TIA

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How did you clean the carb? More than likely, there are plugged passages within it which is not allowing fuel to flow. My suggestion at this point is to just replace the carb. They are relatively cheap, especially for a (assuming) Chinese scooter. Just about anything of the right size would work, but it shouldn't cost you much to change it out.

Comment: Thanks man for the answer.
The carb was cleaned as best I know. Striped completely, everything cleaned, I used small tiny wire for all the passages. Made sure everything was out back correctly. I have no problem to buy NEW carb, but I am no sure that will help. In case it wont what would you suggest as next step.

Comment: You can always attempt to put fuel directly into the carb throat (you can use gasoline, but any flammable spray like carb/brake cleaner will work as well). If the engine fires, it's not getting fuel through the carb. This pretty much would tell you the carb is the issue (for sure). It's not uncommon for small engine carbs to get plugged up where cleaning them doesn't even do the trick.

Comment: Of course I tried that already. Sparkplug is still dry.
Tomorrow I will check timing and valve adjustment.

Comment: Spark plug dry; did you check the fuel feed line from tank to petcock and petcock to carburetor? Sediment. debris, junk may block fuel flow from the tank to fuel lines, internal corrosion of petcock, fuel line to carb. Is fuel in the carburetor or not?